# PHP split text in .txt file via specific symbol

Tags: php

I want to display this as my output.

```
John Michael - 103542 - St. Michael
Kent Yorch - 80410 - St. Regina
Lovely May - 98745 - St. Rosalia
Mark Jess - 45604 - St. Salome
```

This is my .txt file

```
John Michael||St. Michael||103542
Kent Yorch||St. Regina||80410
Lovely May||St. Rosalia||98745
Mark Jess||St. Salome||45604
```

Comment: Did you try anything first?

Comment: We are not here to work for you

Answer (score 2):

```
$file_content = file_get_contents("test.txt");

file_put_contents("test.txt", str_replace(array('|~','~|'),' - ', $file_content));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
str_replace(array("|~","~|"), " - ", $txt);
```

Comment: Can you give me the full code? I dont know how to write it completely.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) and set the optional parameters to match your text format.

So, if we take the example from that link, we can modify it to this:

```
if (($handle = fopen("file.txt", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "|", "~")) !== FALSE) {
        $sOut = implode(' - ', $data);
        echo $sOut . "<br />\n";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$txt=file_get_contents('filename.txt');
$new_txt=str_replace(array("|~","~|"), " - ", $txt);
echo $new_txt;
```

Answer (score 0):

As a  solution to  your problem please try executing code snippet mentioned below.

```
 $file_contents=file_get_contents('abc.txt');
 $contents=str_replace('|~','-',$file_contents); 
 $contents=str_replace('~|','-',$contents);
 echo $contents;
```